# View inflation always null

Tags: java, android

I want to inflate a simple view. But is always Null!

**My code is:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      btStandardBanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          ViewGroup bannerContainer = findViewById(R.id.standardBanner);

            if (bannerContainer == null){
                Log.e("BANNNNNER","IS NULL"); //ALWAYS RUNS HERE
            }else{
                Log.e("BANNNNNER","IS NOT NULL");
            }

          }
        });

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

**And this is my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/standardBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: is R.id.standardBanner part of activity_main layout??

Comment: is `standardBanner` declared in `R.layout.activity_main` ?

Comment: ok, so findViewById(R.id.standardBanner); always returns null ... not much we can change about that

Comment: @Enzokie: I updated my question and added my XML

Comment: Isn't    `ViewGroup bannerContainer` should be `RelativeLayout bannerContainer`

Comment: where is the findViewById() for the `btStandardBanner`?

Comment: how  you are inflating your view ? and also findViewById() for `btStandardBanner` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      findViewById(R.id.standardBanner).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


          // ViewGroup bannerContainer = findViewById(R.id.standardBanner);

            if (bannerContainer == null){
                Log.e("BANNNNNER","IS NULL"); //ALWAYS RUNS HERE
            }else{
                Log.e("BANNNNNER","IS NOT NULL");
            }

          }
        });

    }
```

Your code says you're not initializing the `standardBanner`. 
That's why you're getting `NullPointerException`.

**Another way you can try -**

```
private RelativeLayout bannerContainer;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      bannerContainer = findViewById(R.id.standardBanner);

      bannerContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (bannerContainer == null){
                Log.e("BANNNNNER","IS NULL"); //ALWAYS RUNS HERE
            }else{
                Log.e("BANNNNNER","IS NOT NULL");
            }

          }
        });

    }
```